# Поменять все строки индексы, содержащие даты в формат %Г-%М-%Д %Ч

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\datarn.csv")
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H')
print(df)
```

Я хочу поменять формат строк в моей таблице в формат %Г-%М-%Д %Ч чтобы избавиться от секунд и минут, однако когда хочу это сделать, выдает ошибку

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%Y-%m-%d %H": ":00:00", at position 0. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо избавиться от секунд и минут (все равно вам это **не удастся**, потому что `datetime` сохраняет все в месте как одно большое бинарное число, количество наносекунд).

Вы, наверно, хотите

1. либо **изобразить** (вывести на экран) ваш столбец в более приятном для вас виде, или
2. **конвертировать** его значения в строки (причем вы ***потеряете** все остальное, включая возможностей работать со столбцом как с датами и временами),* или
3. **создать новый столбец** с датами и временами конвертированными в строки.

---

Как это сделать (к предыдущим пунктам):

1. Когда вы работаете в Jupyter Notebook, вы можете **изобразить** столбец `timestamp` так, чтобы он вам нравился, когда вы *как последнюю команду ячейки* используете

   ```
   df.style.format({'timestamp': lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')})
   ```
2. **Конвертирование в строку:**

   ```
   df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
   ```
3. Создание **нового** столбца практически то же самое, но с *новым* именем:

   ```
   df['date-hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
   ```